# Get week start and end days from week number

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get the start and end dates of a given week number. I have tried the following code but it always returns the same date (the current week)

```
val c: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val week = 39
 
c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week)
 
val firstDayOfWeek = c.firstDayOfWeek
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,firstDayOfWeek)
startDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.getDefault()).format(c.time).toString()
 
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, firstDayOfWeek+6)
endDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.getDefault()).format(c.time).toString()
```

Comment: I need the complete date. I have tried to use `c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)` but it still doesn't work

Comment: you can't just add 6 to the day of the week - it's an enum from 1 through 7 (Monday through Sunday) - so for instance, if the first day of the week is Tues, and you add 7, you get 9, which is not a valid value for DAY_OF_WEEK. Look at DayOfWeek.plus()

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I'll update it but do you know the reason why it is giving the current week dates only

Comment: Your code works fine for me if I change the value of ``week`` (week 39 is last week for me, with the default Locale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by calling `c.time` an extra time before using it. Here's the working code :

```
val c: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()//Locale.getDefault())
val week = 39
c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week)
val t = c.time;
val firstDay = c.firstDayOfWeek
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,firstDay)
startDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.getDefault()).format(c.time).toString()
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,firstDay+6)
endDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.getDefault()).format(c.time).toString()
```

Cannot understand why it works, tried it after reading this https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#field-manipulation

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing something or making some basic mistake. Given below is the proof:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
        int week = 39;

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);

        int firstDayOfWeek = c.getFirstDayOfWeek();

        // Start date
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, firstDayOfWeek);
        String startDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        System.out.println(startDate);

        // End date
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, firstDayOfWeek + 6);
        String endDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        System.out.println(endDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-09-21
2020-09-27
```

**Note:** I do not know Kotlin but AFAIK, you can run Java code also in Kotlin. If you want to stick to Kotlin syntax, I hope you should be able to convert it easily into Kotlin syntax.